# css3 jagged edge with transparent bg

Tags: css

I am trying to have jagged edges made in css3 on a div that is on an image and I need it to have a transparent bg, by bg I meant where the jagged edges are

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ovb597yq/

```
<div style="background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ec173a 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-

gradient(135deg, #ec173a 5px, #fff 0) 0 5px;
background-color: #ec173a;
background-position: right top;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-size: 10px 10px;width:200px;height:200px;">test</div>
```

.

```
 body{
        background-image:url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/20090529_Great_Wall_8185.jpg");
}
```

Where its white I am trying to make it transparent but its not currently happening

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply it on `:after` :pseudo-element and change `#fff` to `transparent`.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/20090529_Great_Wall_8185.jpg");
}
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ec173a;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ec173a 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-gradient(135deg, #ec173a 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px;
  background-position: right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: If height is not specified it doesn't work.. I am using divs with text in can be different sizes how can I do this? thanks

Comment: @Jake - Now it will. You have to set the `:after` :pseudo-element's `height` to `100%` for it to take up the entire `height` of the original `div`.