# jagged edges to a div have a border which I can't get rid of

Tags: css, firefox

I have created jagged edges using css on a header element in a wordpress theme I am making. However, my jags have a gray border on them - and I can't work out where this border is coming from.

Edit: I see that this is happening in FF - fine in chrome, max, IE

[image]

Here is the  [link to the site](http://www.fairground.info)

Here is my css:

```
.site-header {
    padding:0;
    max-width:2030px;
    width:100%;
    background:#cdd50e;

    position:relative;
}


.site-header:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;  
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #cdd50e 10px, transparent 0) 0 10px, linear-gradient(225deg, #cdd50e 10px, transparent 0) 0 10px;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left:0px;
  bottom:-20px;
}
```

This css is based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697410/css3-jagged-edge-with-transparent-bg)

Comment: I don't see the grey border in Chrome, but it is present in Firefox... Might help you narrow down the cause

Comment: I was editing this as you posted - thanks

Comment: i dont't see this bug, https://yadi.sk/d/uUX2CfT03CHxEA look screen

Comment: Don't see any issues on latest firefox & chrome for mac

Comment: I am running Firefox 51.0.1 and the bug is there. I'm not sure what is causing it. Have you tried the moz linear-gradient prefix?

Comment: I have tried the -moz-linear-gradient... and same effect.

Comment: Serg - thanks for the Screen Shots - what version of FF are you on?